# Install Julia >v1.1.1 on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: audio, compilation, raspberry-pi, julia, portaudio

I'm trying to use the PortAudio package in Julia on a Raspberry Pi Zero W running Raspberry Pi OS like so:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("PortAudio")
```

This fails with the error:

```
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package PortAudio [80ea8bcb]:
 PortAudio [80ea8bcb] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 1.1.1-1.1.2 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 1.1.1-1.1.2
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

The version of Julia in `apt` is v1.0.3, which explains the above error. So I'm trying to install the latest version of Julia. The [pre-compiled binaries](https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/#lianux_and_freebsd) won't run (`Illegal instruction` error) so I'm trying to compile it following the instructions from [here](https://juliaberry.github.io/compile.html):

```
sudo apt-get -y update 
sudo apt-get install build-essential libatomic1 python gfortran perl wget m4 cmake pkg-config libopenblas-dev git ccache
```

I then added this to `/etc/dphys-swapfile`

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=8192
CONF_MAXSWAP=8192
```

Then

```
git clone https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git
cd julia
git checkout v1.6.2
make
```

This fails with this error:

```
Illegal instruction
make[1]: *** [Makefile:222: julia_flisp.boot] Error 132
make: *** [Makefile:43: julia_flisp.boot.inc.phony] Error 2
```

I think the issue here is that you need to tell it which ARM CPU the Pi uses, so following [these instructions](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/doc/build/arm.md#raspberry-pi-1--raspberry-pi-zero) and [this thread](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33929) I added this to `Make.user`:

```
JULIA_CPU_TARGET=arm1176jzf-s
USE_BINARYBUILDER=0
```

But I get the same error, albeit with a suggestion to try `make -C deps clean-openblas` and rebuild with `make OPENBLAS_USE_THREAD=0` or `make OPENBLAS_TARGET_ARCH=NEHALEM`. Neither fixes the problem. Also tried [this python script](https://github.com/johnnychen94/jill.py) (`error downloading julia-1.6-latest` ) and [these instructions to install via docker](https://gist.github.com/terasakisatoshi/3f8a55391b1fc22a5db4a43da8d92c98) (`standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`) but could not get either to work.

I've tried absolutely everything I can find online. Someone please help! How do I install a recent version (>v1.1.1) of Julia on a Pi Zero?

Comment: To install the latest Julia (LTS version) for Linux ARM you can follow the instruction on this link : https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/#linux_and_freebsd

Comment: For `Unsatisfiable requirements` in the REPL you could try:
`] rm General` ,
`add General` ,
`up General` ,
this should fix the corrupted binaries.

Comment: Hi @MohammadSaad, thanks for your answers. I've using the ARM binary from the link you gave, I get the error `Illegal instruction` when I try to run it. Any idea why?

Comment: Just tried `] rm General`, `add General`, `up General`, still getting the same error `ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements...`. Isn't the issue here that I need to upgrade the to 1.1.1 or higher? `possible versions are: 1.1.1-1.1.2 or uninstalled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it! Code quoted from [this website](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/have-a-try-julia-v1-5-1-for-arm32bit/45558):

```
yourmainPC $ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local # Assume You are going to login to your Pi via SSH
pi@raspberrypi $ curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && sh get-docker.sh
pi@raspberrypi $ sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker # if you like to skip `sudo`
pi@raspberrypi $ exit
yourmainPC $ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local # login again
pi@raspberrypi $ JL_VERSION=v1.5.1
pi@raspberrypi $ IMAGE_NAME=terasakisatoshi/jlcross:rpizero-${JL_VERSION}
pi@raspberrypi $ CONTAINER_NAME=jltmp_${JL_VERSION}
pi@raspberrypi $ docker run --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} $IMAGE_NAME /bin/bash
pi@raspberrypi $ docker cp ${CONTAINER_NAME}:/home/pi/julia-${JL_VERSION} .
pi@raspberrypi $ docker rm ${CONTAINER_NAME}
pi@raspberrypi $ ls 
julia-v1.5.1 # <---- this is it
pi@raspberrypi $ cd julia-v1.5.1/bin
pi@raspberrypi $ ./julia # tada!!!
```